# How to link the location of opencv libraries into the python file (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2')

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

So I wrote a little “Hello World” for Python (3.10.4) and OpenCV that does the following:

1. Read an image from a folder called "images"
2. Display the image
3. Print “Hello World” to the console.

If I use the command `python hello_world.py` in Anaconda (without activating any environment) it works perfectly. But if I do the same in the normal Windows Terminal, I get the error
`“ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'”` – so I assume, Anaconda knows where to look for OpenCV but the “normal” terminal doesn’t. How do I add the information directly to the script or the function call?

The reason I cannot use Anaconda to run it is, that I have to transfer the script to a Linux-Board where I don’t have Anaconda or similar (in fact, I won’t even have an internet connection on the board). So I somehow have to add the information to either the function call or the script itself but I have no clue, how to do this.

On Windows, OpenCV can be found here: `C:/opencv/build/python/cv2`

And on the Linux board, the libraries seem to be here `/usr/lib/python3.10`

If you could give me a foolproof step-by-step guide on how to link OpenCV, I would be very grateful!

Here is the full hello_world.py script

```
import cv2 #I think I need to be more specific here?
import os
import sys


def main():

    # Check if the script is run from its own directory
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    image_subfolder = os.path.join(script_directory, "images")

    if not os.path.exists(image_subfolder):
        print("Error: 'images' subfolder not found.")
        sys.exit(1)

    image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_subfolder) if f.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg'))]

    if not image_files:
        print("Error: No image files found in the 'images' subfolder.")
        sys.exit(1)

    image_path = os.path.join(image_subfolder, image_files[0])

    # Read and display the image using OpenCV
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Print "Hello World" to the console
    print("Hello World")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't installed all your dependencies on your Windows python environment.

Easiest would be to install it by opening a new terminal and run:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

(This is already described in https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#installation-and-usage)

For the long read around dependencies, see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/managing-dependencies/